# Ngrx update reducer if component is on the page

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have two components on a page, an update user form and a history of events. They are represented by two reducers (user and events). I want to update the list of events in the store (by calling an API) once once the user has been updated. However, the events should only be updated if the events component is on the page.

What's the best way to achieve this? The only solution I like the idea of is to have a success handler in a parent of the form / event components which dispatches an action which is caught by an effect which will then refresh the list of events. I was hoping this is something I could achieve entirely with effects but I obviously don't know if the component Is on the page and I also need access to route params. Does anyone have any better solutions or can see an issue with this solution?

Comment: Dispatch an action to your store with `ngOnInit` hook of your events component which sets an `canUpdate` flag in your state. And if the component is destroyed set the `canUpdate` flag to false again.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the fact that the **Events component is shown on the screen** represents some sort of part of the "business logic/process" which is likely already represented **in the store state**. If it is not the case, you seem to need to add it in some way and update it when your **events** component initializes (**ngOnInit**) and is destroyed (**ngOnDestroy**).

Once it is part of the store, you can use it as part of the effect.